# 6-Characters minimum on editing with tag edit

Tags: bug, editing, suggested-edits, retagging

I tried to edit a question because it was tagged badly. It seemed mostly fine otherwise, though I decided to fix 2 punctuation and one capitalization errors (which would not normally warrant a suggested edit). However, The system told me

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

My edit was more than six characters/changes if you include the tags I fixed. I think tag-edits with no body changes are also allowed, so I think this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: I don't understand why you consider this to be a bug. Edits to post body texts should be substantial. This is independent from any retagging. Otherwise there'd be an easy workaround for any "substantial edits only" rule by retagging. Please explain in more detail how having independent requirements for mostly independent actions ([editing tags](http://superuser.com/privileges/retag-questions) and [editing post bodies](http://superuser.com/privileges/edit)), that have a common, convenient interface, is a bug.

Comment: I feel like I am being discouraged from editing while fixing tags, since I would need to make a substantial body edit while editing tgs if I wanted to correct something. I see what you mean by an edit workarund though.

Comment: I was thinking of them as a single action.

Comment: I was hit with this TOTALLY STUPID rule as well. I wanted to correct one little mistake made by someone else: change `kbd>` into `<kbd>`, so that a key would properly show on screen. And I can't do that unless I am willing to substantially alter the rest of the question as well? Who comes up with these limitations?