# Edits must be at least 6 characters when only editing tags?

Tags: bug, editing, suggested-edits, retagging

I tried to retag [this question](https://superuser.com/q/102020/513819) to add the [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp) tags, but it wouldn't let me submit my edit because it said that it was less than 6 characters:

[image]

At first I thought that it was because of [this issue](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5584/513819) because I accidentally did something in the body without noticing, so I clicked Cancel and then tried to edit again and it did the same thing. I tried again and again and always got the same problem. So I'm sure that I didn't touch the body, only the tags.

The strange thing is that I successfully submitted [another retag](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/630590) today and several retags in the past without getting this problem, and I regularly see tag edits on Stack Overflow where I have the privilege to review suggested edits, so normally edits just editing the tags should be allowed.

Is there a reason why I couldn't submit this specific retag without editing the body while I've submitted many other retags in the past without any problem? If this is a bug, please fix it.

Comment: You shouldn't be editing that question at all. Your edit doesn't improve the question at all and the question has already been flagged/closed as a duplicate.

Comment: First, if you are using #windows you shouldn't also use a version specific tag like #windows-xp its one or the other.  the #windows tag should be avoided when possible because its to generic.  While that is the case, retagging a question that has been closed for 7 years as a duplicate, doesn't really do anything to improve the quality of that question.  If anything you should have only used #windows to matcht the tag of the duplicate question.